# django api post without bring json still work?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Because django rest framework did not support bulk create
So I write one
And I found a strange problem
if I `POST` the api with a `json` like  :

```
[{'address':'1','name':'2','start':'3'},
{'address':'10','name':'20','start':'30'}]
```

it works!
But if I kust `POST` the api without bring `json`
I still got `bulk create success` message.
Why would this happen??
Where do I write wrong??

This is my API view

```
class BulkTestList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        duplicateList = []
        for data in request.data:
            message = {}
            if not 'address' in data.keys():
                message['address'] = [ "This field is required."]
            elif not data['address']:
                message["address"] = [ "This field may not be blank."]
            if not 'name' in data.keys():
                message["name"] = [ "This field is required."]
            elif not data['name']:
                message["name"]= [ "This field may not be blank."]
            if not 'star' in data.keys():
                message["star"] = [ "This field is required."]
            elif not data['star']:
                message["star"]= [ "This field may not be blank."]

            if message:
                return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        for data in request.data:
            address = data['address'].upper()
            bulkCreateObjects = Data(address=address, name=data['name'], star=data['star'], datetime=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
            bulkCreateObjects.save()
        message = {"bulk create success"}
        return Response(data=message, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST framework doesn't have bulk out of the box but you have a third party app that does.

Your current view just doesn't call a serializer therefore you won't get the validation at any point. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views

Note that for bulk you'll add a many=True to the serializer so it will be able to deal with list of data.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue that the view returns a 201 "{bulk create success}" is due to the fact that you iteration over request.data does not check if reuqest.data is actually empty. A for loop over an empty list will just skip over the for block. As Linovia mentions, you need to add some validation to your view.